# Hot chocolate Enum serialization issue in .NET core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hotchocolate

When I request the data from banana cake pop I get the following error
**{
"message": "EmployeeType cannot serialize the given value.",
"extensions": {
"code": "EXEC_INVALID_LEAF_VALUE"
}
}**
As per hot chocolate enum are serialized by default.
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/enums
But still getting error

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Schema + Query + Varaibles maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was seeding data and accidently that field got null, which caused this error as I changed that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because one of the enum values was missing. The database contained a `3` for enum value, but the code only contained 3 values (so `0`, `1` and `2`).